# How to fullfill this indirect dependency requirement in setup?

Tags: python, dependencies

```
ERROR: tensorflow 2.3.0 has requirement scipy==1.4.1, but you'll have scipy 1.5.2 which is incompatible.
```

When I do pip install -r requirments.txt, I saw this error message above. However, in my requirements.txt, I don't have this scipy listed. It might be due to:

```
scikit-learn==0.22.1
```

In such a case, how can I get rid of this error message in my requirments.txt by making changes in my dependencies?